# JS-jQuery - getting value of id for each row of a table while reading from API

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to find out but no way :( I am open to use or JS only or jQuery.
I am reading from my API objects 'Expense' for each of them, I've hidden the id.
Adding the functionnality of deletion, i'ld like to catch the id of the concerned row while clicking delete in order to call via AJAX a delete method request.

**Here is my append - data from my API**

```
function fetchExpenses(){ 
    fetchExpensesJson()
        .then ( res => 
                res.expensesList.forEach((expense) => {
                    var expenseToAdd = "<tr>"
                                            + "<td class='hidden-id'>" + expense.id +"</td>"
                                            + "<td class='table-body-row'>" + expense.amount + "</td>"
                                            + "<td class='table-body-row'>" + expense.currency + "</td>"
                                            + "<td class='table-body-row'>" + expense.shop + "</td>"
                                            + "<td class='table-body-row'>" + expense.comment + "</td>"
                                            + "<td class='table-body-row'>" + expense.documentNumber + "</td>"
                                            + "<td class='table-body-row'>" + expense.coverageFrom + "</td>"
                                            + "<td class='table-body-row'>" + expense.coverageTo + "</td>"
                                            + "<td class='table-body-row'>Edit</td>"
                                            + "<td class='table-body-row' id='deletion-table-body-row'><button id='deletion-btn-table-body-row'>Delete</button></td>"
                                        + "</tr>";
                    $("#expenses-table-body").append(expenseToAdd);
                })
        
        );
}
```

As you can see the 'edit' is not implemented yet.

Here is the way how I'm trying to reach each of id's:

```
 $(document).on("click","#deletion-btn-table-body-row", function(event){   
    console.log("accessing deletion process");
    const smthg = document.querySelector('#deletion-table-body-row').previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.innerText;
    console.log(smthg);
});
```

While trying to reach individually ID - expense.id - of each row, I am always receiving the id of the first line of the table... how can you do to get individualy for each line, each id - expense.id ?

Please note that I'm totally aware of the fact that accumulation of ".previousElementSibling" is not a good patent :)

Thank you for any response/help.

Comment: Ids must be unique..

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using jQuery on how to get your ids from the row in which you clicked the delete button. Notable changes are that I've changed the button id to use a class instead.

```js
$('button.deletion-btn-table-body-row').click(function(){
  console.log($(this).parent().closest('tr').find('td.hidden-id').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="hidden-id">1</td>
<td class="table-body-row">Amount</td>
<td class="table-body-row">Currency</td>
<td class="table-body-row">Shop</td>
<td class="table-body-row">Comment</td>
<td class="table-body-row">DocumentNumber</td>
<td class="table-body-row">CoverageFrom</td>
<td class="table-body-row">CoverageTo</td>
<td class="table-body-row">Edit</td>
<td class='table-body-row' id='deletion-table-body-row'><button class='deletion-btn-table-body-row'>Delete</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="hidden-id">2</td>
<td class="table-body-row">Amount</td>
<td class="table-body-row">Currency</td>
<td class="table-body-row">Shop</td>
<td class="table-body-row">Comment</td>
<td class="table-body-row">DocumentNumber</td>
<td class="table-body-row">CoverageFrom</td>
<td class="table-body-row">CoverageTo</td>
<td class="table-body-row">Edit</td>
<td class='table-body-row' id='deletion-table-body-row'><button class='deletion-btn-table-body-row'>Delete</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="hidden-id">3</td>
<td class="table-body-row">Amount</td>
<td class="table-body-row">Currency</td>
<td class="table-body-row">Shop</td>
<td class="table-body-row">Comment</td>
<td class="table-body-row">DocumentNumber</td>
<td class="table-body-row">CoverageFrom</td>
<td class="table-body-row">CoverageTo</td>
<td class="table-body-row">Edit</td>
<td class='table-body-row' id='deletion-table-body-row'><button class='deletion-btn-table-body-row'>Delete</button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Edit: What's most likely happening is because you are using an id on that button, when you are clicking it, it's using the first one in the table that it finds each time.

Comment: That's amazingly brilliant! Thank you very much, still a lot of stuff for me to learn on here..